# Is it possible to partition more than one way at a time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm considering various ways to partition my data in SQL Server.  One approach I'm looking at is to partition a particular huge table into 8 partitions, then within each of these partitions to partition on a different partition column.  Is this even possible in SQL Server, or am I limited to definining one parition column+function+scheme per table?

I'm interested in the more general answer, but this strategy is one I'm considering for Distributed Partitioned View, where I'd partition the data under the first scheme using DPV to distribute the huge amount of data over 8 machines, and then on each machine partition that portion of the full table on another parition key in order to be able to drop (for example) sub-paritions as required.

Comment: What performance problem are you trying to resolve?  

A partitioned table consisting of 5 partitions isn't built up of 5 sub tables rather its one table with 5 data stores. The function controls where to read / write the data from. You can have 256 partitions in a single table (21 Years of one month to a table from partitioning in a typical system.) What are you trying to do in the function?

Comment: Performance is one aspect, but its more a data volume issue.  We can't fit all the data on a single instance (factoring for future growth) so distributing the data across multiple servers seems to be the logical choice to solve this.  I had also hoped to partition based on another attribute of the entities and with DPV this would equate to wanting to do a 2nd partitioning of the data on each database instance.  This 2nd partitioning is not so much about direct performance (though it would reduce contention) but rather ability to rebuild indexes and drop slices.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect that the partitioning key cannot be computed. Use a computed, persisted column for the key:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD PartitionID AS ISNULL(Column1 * Column2,0) persisted
```

I do it all the time, very simple.

Answer (score 0):

The DPV across a set of Partitioned Tables is your only clean option to achieve this, something like a DPV across tblSales2007, tblSales2008, tblSales2009, and then each of the respective sales tables are partitioned again, but they could then be partitioned by a different key. There are some very good benefits in doing this in terms of operational resiliance (one partitioned table going offline does not take the DPV down - it can satisfy queries for the other timelines still)

The hack option is to create an arbitary hash of 2 columns and store this per record, and partition by it. You would have to generate this hash for every query / insertion etc since the partition key can not be computed, it must be a stored value. It's a hack and I suspect would lose more performance than you would gain.

You do have to be thinking of specific management issues / DR over data quantities though, if the data volumes are very large and you are accessing it in a primarily read mechanism then you should look into SQL 'Madison' which will scale enormously in both number of rows as well as overall size of data. But it really only suits the 99.9% read type data warehouse, it is not suitable for an OLTP.

I have production data sets sitting in the 'billions' bracket, and they reside on partitioned table systems and provide very good performance - although much of this is based on the hardware underlying a system, not the database itself. Scalaing up to this level is not an issue and I know of other's who have gone well beyond those quantities as well.

The max partitions per table remains at 1000, from what I remember of a conversation about this, it was a figure set by the testing performed - not a figure in place due to a technical limitation.